System goes into unresponsive "suspend" instead of shutting down when closing lid during shutdown (Kubuntu 24.04 LTS)
EDIT: After some testing, I can now reproduce the problem. When I close the lid immediately after clicking "shutdown", the system goes into suspend instead of shutting down. When opening the lid again, the screen wakes up but freezes (mouse can be moved but nothing else). This happens although I have set the closing-lid-behaivour to "do nothing" or "turn off screen" (no difference) in the energy saving settings.
I tried disabling tlp but it didn't solve the issue. In similar problems (like here for Kubuntu 19.10), the system finally shuts down after opening the lid again. In my case, the system freezes.
I added an excerpt of the /var/log/syslog below. It starts with me requesting a "shutdown" and ends with the system going into "suspend" around 9 seconds after that. (The last line comes from the next morning, when I used REISUB.)
2024-09-08T23:15:11.861506+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 dbus-daemon[1694]: [session uid=1000 pid=1694] Activating service name='org.kde.LogoutPrompt' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1000 pid=1937 comm="/usr/bin/ksmserver" label="unconfined")
2024-09-08T23:15:11.997074+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 dbus-daemon[1694]: [session uid=1000 pid=1694] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.LogoutPrompt'
2024-09-08T23:15:14.220349+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 dbus-daemon[1694]: [session uid=1000 pid=1694] Activating service name='org.kde.Shutdown' requested by ':1.945' (uid=1000 pid=17871 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/ksmserver-logout" label="unconfined")
2024-09-08T23:15:14.236808+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 dbus-daemon[1694]: [session uid=1000 pid=1694] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.Shutdown'
2024-09-08T23:15:14.327188+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: Service  ":1.86" unregistered
2024-09-08T23:15:14.370178+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: plasma-krunner.service: Consumed 2.140s CPU time.
2024-09-08T23:15:14.432679+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: app-org.kde.discover.notifier@autostart.service: Consumed 1.710s CPU time.
2024-09-08T23:15:14.453256+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: app-kup\x2ddaemon@autostart.service: Consumed 1.089s CPU time.
2024-09-08T23:15:14.459327+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: plasma-ksystemstats.service: Consumed 7.247s CPU time.
2024-09-08T23:15:14.462647+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: app-org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon@autostart.service: Consumed 1.879s CPU time.
2024-09-08T23:15:15.166126+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Consumed 28min 12.888s CPU time.
2024-09-08T23:15:15.869767+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-09-08T23:15:18.974054+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0x85 on isa0060/serio0).
2024-09-08T23:15:18.974075+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e005 <keycode>' to make it known.
2024-09-08T23:15:18.980778+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1725830118.979:259): pid=997 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=4445 label="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" peer_pid=1035 peer_label="unconfined"
2024-09-08T23:15:18.980787+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
2024-09-08T23:15:19.414549+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: Service  ":1.99" unregistered
2024-09-08T23:15:19.421861+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped target plasma-workspace-x11.target.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.422030+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped target plasma-workspace.target - KDE Plasma Workspace.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.423259+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped target xdg-desktop-autostart.target - Startup of XDG autostart applications.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.423585+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping app-geoclue\x2ddemo\x2dagent@autostart.service - Geoclue Demo agent...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.423826+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping app-joplin\x2ddesktop_joplin\x2ddesktop@autostart.service - Joplin...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.424338+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping app-kaccess@autostart.service - Accessibility...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.424444+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping app-org.gnome.Evolution\x2dalarm\x2dnotify@autostart.service - Events and Tasks Reminders...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.425092+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping app-org.kde.kclock@autostart.service - org.kde.kclock...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.426973+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping app-signal\x2ddesktop@autostart.service - Signal...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.427678+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping app-syncthing\x2dstart@autostart.service - Start Syncthing...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.430129+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping app-touchegg@autostart.service - Touchégg...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.430702+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping at-spi-dbus-bus.service - Accessibility services bus...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.431849+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 syncthing[2198]: [monitor] 2024/09/08 23:15:19 INFO: Signal 15 received; exiting
2024-09-08T23:15:19.432085+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping flatpak-session-helper.service - flatpak session helper...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.432185+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping plasma-baloorunner.service - KRunner provider for baloo file indexer...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.432271+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping plasma-kglobalaccel.service - KDE Global Shortcuts Server...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.432442+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping plasma-kscreen.service - KScreen...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.432559+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping plasma-kwin_x11.service - KDE Window Manager...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.432862+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping plasma-powerdevil.service - Powerdevil...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.433046+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping plasma-xdg-desktop-portal-kde.service - Xdg Desktop Portal For KDE...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.433314+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.433539+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.433916+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping xdg-permission-store.service - sandboxed app permission store...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.441290+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped xdg-permission-store.service - sandboxed app permission store.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.442536+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.448566+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1]: run-user-1000-doc.mount: Deactivated successfully.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.450356+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 syncthing[2198]: [AY3J6] 2024/09/08 23:15:19 INFO: Relay listener (dynamic+https://relays.syncthing.net/endpoint) shutting down
2024-09-08T23:15:19.450618+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 syncthing[2198]: [AY3J6] 2024/09/08 23:15:19 INFO: QUIC listener ([::]:22000) shutting down
2024-09-08T23:15:19.451904+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1725830119.450:260): pid=997 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=4445 label="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" peer_pid=1035 peer_label="unconfined"
2024-09-08T23:15:19.451915+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
2024-09-08T23:15:19.451917+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1725830119.450:261): pid=997 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=4445 label="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" peer_pid=1035 peer_label="unconfined"
2024-09-08T23:15:19.451919+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
2024-09-08T23:15:19.453793+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped plasma-ksmserver.service - KDE Session Management Server.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.462369+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 signal-desktop[2188]: [2188:0908/231519.461050:ERROR:zygote_communication_linux.cc(292)] Failed to send GetTerminationStatus message to zygote
2024-09-08T23:15:19.467363+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1725830119.462:262): pid=997 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="PrepareForSleep" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=2153 label="snap.joplin-desktop.joplin-desktop" peer_pid=1035 peer_label="unconfined"
2024-09-08T23:15:19.467381+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
2024-09-08T23:15:19.467383+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1725830119.462:263): pid=997 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="PrepareForSleep" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=4445 label="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" peer_pid=1035 peer_label="unconfined"
2024-09-08T23:15:19.467384+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
2024-09-08T23:15:19.467386+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1725830119.465:264): pid=997 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=4445 label="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" peer_pid=1035 peer_label="unconfined"
2024-09-08T23:15:19.467388+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
2024-09-08T23:15:19.466379+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped plasma-kglobalaccel.service - KDE Global Shortcuts Server.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.466753+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 ModemManager[1198]: <msg> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
2024-09-08T23:15:19.467024+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped plasma-powerdevil.service - Powerdevil.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.467116+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: plasma-powerdevil.service: Consumed 1.361s CPU time.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.467194+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped plasma-xdg-desktop-portal-kde.service - Xdg Desktop Portal For KDE.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.467290+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped app-org.kde.kclock@autostart.service - org.kde.kclock.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.470916+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped app-touchegg@autostart.service - Touchégg.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.471322+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830119.4680] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
2024-09-08T23:15:19.471441+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped app-geoclue\x2ddemo\x2dagent@autostart.service - Geoclue Demo agent.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.471520+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped app-kaccess@autostart.service - Accessibility.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.471595+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped flatpak-session-helper.service - flatpak session helper.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.471670+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped plasma-kscreen.service - KScreen.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.471883+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped at-spi-dbus-bus.service - Accessibility services bus.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.472777+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped plasma-baloorunner.service - KRunner provider for baloo file indexer.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.474083+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped app-org.gnome.Evolution\x2dalarm\x2dnotify@autostart.service - Events and Tasks Reminders.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.475092+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.475874+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1725830119.472:265): pid=997 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=4445 label="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" peer_pid=1035 peer_label="unconfined"
2024-09-08T23:15:19.475960+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
2024-09-08T23:15:19.477961+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: app-org.keepassxc.KeePassXC-7de9ca953afb45c79f1b0e6ffc5cf270.scope: Consumed 2.801s CPU time.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.478613+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped target plasma-core.target - KDE Plasma Workspace Core.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.479147+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[5359]: klauncher: Exiting on signal 15
2024-09-08T23:15:19.479503+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopping plasma-kded.service - KDE Daemon...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.480359+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*
2024-09-08T23:15:19.482423+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: message repeated 3 times: [ QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*]
2024-09-08T23:15:19.483498+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830119.4833] device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2024-09-08T23:15:19.485229+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*
2024-09-08T23:15:19.486952+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: message repeated 2 times: [ QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*]
2024-09-08T23:15:19.487348+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 signal-desktop[2188]: [2188:0908/231519.486839:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(600)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.496551+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830119.4964] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
2024-09-08T23:15:19.496932+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830119.4968] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2024-09-08T23:15:19.505397+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 dbus-daemon[997]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=1118 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon" label="unconfined")
2024-09-08T23:15:19.512940+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*
2024-09-08T23:15:19.515745+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1725830119.514:266): pid=997 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=4445 label="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" peer_pid=1035 peer_label="unconfined"
2024-09-08T23:15:19.515760+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
2024-09-08T23:15:19.520421+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: message repeated 8 times: [ QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*]
2024-09-08T23:15:19.523321+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
2024-09-08T23:15:19.525342+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*
2024-09-08T23:15:19.526354+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 signal-desktop[2188]: Render process is gone: Error: Reason: killed, Exit Code: 15
2024-09-08T23:15:19.526666+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 signal-desktop[2188]:     at App.<anonymous> (/opt/Signal/resources/app.asar/app/global_errors.js:94:7)
2024-09-08T23:15:19.526773+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 signal-desktop[2188]:     at App.emit (node:events:519:28)
2024-09-08T23:15:19.526834+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 signal-desktop[2188]:     at WebContents.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:84566)
2024-09-08T23:15:19.526888+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 signal-desktop[2188]:     at WebContents.emit (node:events:519:28)
2024-09-08T23:15:19.527163+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*
2024-09-08T23:15:19.532148+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 dbus-daemon[997]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
2024-09-08T23:15:19.532270+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*
2024-09-08T23:15:19.532356+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.533370+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*
2024-09-08T23:15:19.540871+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 04:b4:fe:0d:26:bf by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
2024-09-08T23:15:19.597463+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: message repeated 6 times: [ QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*]
2024-09-08T23:15:19.598372+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 syncthing[2198]: [AY3J6] 2024/09/08 23:15:19 INFO: TCP listener ([::]:22000) shutting down
2024-09-08T23:15:19.598508+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*
2024-09-08T23:15:19.598958+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 syncthing[2198]: [AY3J6] 2024/09/08 23:15:19 INFO: Exiting
2024-09-08T23:15:19.599155+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*
2024-09-08T23:15:19.599288+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kded5[1939]: QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*
2024-09-08T23:15:19.600696+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 krunner[4398]: kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
2024-09-08T23:15:19.608423+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped app-syncthing\x2dstart@autostart.service - Start Syncthing.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.608612+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: app-syncthing\x2dstart@autostart.service: Consumed 13.178s CPU time.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.643002+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped plasma-kded.service - KDE Daemon.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.643113+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: plasma-kded.service: Consumed 10.193s CPU time.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.645726+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped plasma-kwin_x11.service - KDE Window Manager.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.645831+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: plasma-kwin_x11.service: Consumed 13min 43.466s CPU time.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.666403+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 wpa_supplicant[1127]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=04:b4:fe:0d:26:bf reason=3 locally_generated=1
2024-09-08T23:15:19.666847+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 wpa_supplicant[1127]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
2024-09-08T23:15:19.666941+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 wpa_supplicant[1127]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
2024-09-08T23:15:19.667037+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830119.6669] device (wlp3s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2024-09-08T23:15:19.667585+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830119.6675] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
2024-09-08T23:15:19.667691+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830119.6675] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
2024-09-08T23:15:19.667796+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830119.6675] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed no lease
2024-09-08T23:15:19.668120+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830119.6680] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
2024-09-08T23:15:19.668208+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830119.6680] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
2024-09-08T23:15:19.668277+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830119.6681] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed no lease
2024-09-08T23:15:19.668619+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 avahi-daemon[990]: Withdrawing address record for 2a00:1e:cf00:d501:6d40:ff99:3c83:245c on wlp3s0.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.668685+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 avahi-daemon[990]: Withdrawing address record for 2a00:1e:cf00:d501:3935:4569:67e4:f6a5 on wlp3s0.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.668776+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 avahi-daemon[990]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address 2a00:1e:cf00:d501:3935:4569:67e4:f6a5.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.668844+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 avahi-daemon[990]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::1dea:dd87:988c:4a83.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.668887+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 avahi-daemon[990]: Registering new address record for fe80::1dea:dd87:988c:4a83 on wlp3s0.*.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.668930+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 avahi-daemon[990]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::1dea:dd87:988c:4a83 on wlp3s0.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.668971+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 avahi-daemon[990]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::1dea:dd87:988c:4a83.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.669013+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 avahi-daemon[990]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.670631+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd-resolved[747]: wlp3s0: Bus client reset search domain list.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.672500+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 avahi-daemon[990]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.178.31 on wlp3s0.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.672597+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd-resolved[747]: wlp3s0: Bus client set default route setting: no
2024-09-08T23:15:19.672643+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 avahi-daemon[990]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.178.31.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.673857+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd-resolved[747]: wlp3s0: Bus client reset DNS server list.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.744673+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: Stopped app-joplin\x2ddesktop_joplin\x2ddesktop@autostart.service - Joplin.
2024-09-08T23:15:19.748671+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1677]: snap.joplin-desktop.joplin-desktop-40d958a7-d63a-4f23-9640-8e02b6dda124.scope: Consumed 2min 25.773s CPU time.
2024-09-08T23:15:20.111186+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 avahi-daemon[990]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
2024-09-08T23:15:20.131032+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830120.1309] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
2024-09-08T23:15:20.131387+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 NetworkManager[1118]: <info>  [1725830120.1313] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2024-09-08T23:15:20.157741+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1725830120.156:267): pid=997 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=4445 label="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" peer_pid=1035 peer_label="unconfined"
2024-09-08T23:15:20.157763+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel:  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
2024-09-08T23:15:20.158040+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 wpa_supplicant[1127]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
2024-09-08T23:15:20.159762+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1]: Reached target sleep.target - Sleep.
2024-09-08T23:15:20.175331+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1]: Starting syncthing-resume.service - Restart Syncthing after resume...
2024-09-08T23:15:20.176477+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
2024-09-08T23:15:20.184517+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 wpa_supplicant[1127]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
2024-09-08T23:15:20.184583+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 wpa_supplicant[1127]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
2024-09-08T23:15:20.191396+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1]: syncthing-resume.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-09-08T23:15:20.191519+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd[1]: Finished syncthing-resume.service - Restart Syncthing after resume.
2024-09-08T23:15:20.228908+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
2024-09-08T23:15:20.229118+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 systemd-sleep[17990]: Performing sleep operation 'suspend'...
2024-09-08T23:15:20.235737+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.006 seconds
2024-09-09T09:13:40.803638+02:00 kevin-hpprobook450g6 kernel: Freezing user space processes

